# Installing Android SDK with minimal setup.

Tags: android

I'm new To android ecosystem.

Do I really need to install all the SDK from Android 1.5 to Android 4.1? to create an app which will support almost all the Android versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, one should be fine. Pick the latest one. So 4.1 be it!

Just set your apps mininum sdk version to the desired api level.

Eclipse should warn you if you use stuff that aint working on that minumum version.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I really need to install all the SDK from Android 1.5 to Android 4.1? to create an app which will support almost all the Android versions

You need to test your app on any version that you intend to support. For those Android versions that you have a physical device for, you can test your app on that (most likely). For anything else, you will at least need to download the emulator images, so you can create emulators for those older Android versions.